# Running a batch file which schedules a Task with Wix on Uninstall

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, uninstallation, windows-task-scheduler

I have the following XML in my .wxs file for running a batch file on uninstall:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="uninstall_action" After="InstallInitialize">Installed AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

and

```
<Fragment>
  <CustomAction 
    Id         ="uninstall_action"
    Directory  ="INSTALLDIR"
    ExeCommand ="&quot;[INSTALLDIR]uninstallTester.bat&quot;"
    Execute    ="deferred"
    Impersonate="no"
  />
</Fragment>
```

So it should run a batch file located in the install directory. My batch file looks like this:

```
schtasks /Create /F /SC ONCE /ST 22:05 /TN exampleUninstall /TR "echo hello" 2> batch_log.log
```

When I run the uninstaller I get the following inside the batch_log.log:

```
ERROR: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.
(40,4):UserId:
```

It seems to have a problem specifically only with creating a new scheduled task, because if I change the batch to remove a scheduled task, it runs without error. So my question is: how can I schedule this one time task to run? Also running the batch file by itself will also work, it just has a problem when being called by the uninstaller.

I've also tried googling that specific error with no luck.

I've simplified my actual use case, so I cannot merely just move the schtasks command into the ExecCommand in the installer, it must live inside a batch file (actually it will live inside an executable, but I thought this batch example is easier)

Comment: You can try adding /RU "SYSTEM" to your cmd. I've never run schtasks but it might work? It sounds like there's some confusion between user logged into the machine but running the tasks under system context.

Comment: @BrianSutherland That seemed to do the trick. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding /RU "SYSTEM" to your cmd. I've never run schtasks but it might work? It sounds like there's some confusion between user logged into the machine but running the tasks under system context.